# Trying to hide a HTML 'label' using CSS 'hide'

Tags: css

Should be simple enough but it doesn't seem to work.

I am trying to hide a checkbox on a login form that says "Remember Me" on my membership site.

Here is the relevant bit of HTML:

```
<label><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" /> Remember Me</label>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.rememberme {
  display: none
}
```

No joy.

Any idea how I hide that 'label' string of HTML?

Thanks

++++ EDIT ++++

I added the entire code to help with this question. Thanks again for all  help!

```
<form name="mepr_loginform" id="mepr_loginform" class="mepr-form" action="https://my-site.com/login/" method="post">
    <div class="mp-form-row mepr_username">
        <div class="mp-form-label">
            <label for="log">Username</label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="log" id="user_login" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="mp-form-row mepr_password">
        <div class="mp-form-label">
            <label for="pwd">Password</label>
        </div>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" id="user_pass" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="mp-form-row mepr_math_captcha">
        <div class="mp-form-label">
            <label for="meprmath_quiz"><span id="meprmath_captcha-5cf739drre412c84"></span>*</label>
        </div>
        <input type="text" name="meprmath_quiz" id="meprmath_quiz" value="" class="mepr-form-input" />
        <input type="hidden" name="meprmath_data" value="sdasDDDDI4YWYxYmIzYWIxODU=" />
            <script>Removed b/c not important to this question</script>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label><input name="rememberme" type="checkbox" id="rememberme" value="forever" />Remember Me</label>
    </div>
    <div class="mp-spacer">&nbsp;</div>
    <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="wp-submit" id="wp-submit" class="button-primary mepr-share-button " value="Log In" />
        <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to" value="https://my-site.com/account/" />
        <input type="hidden" name="mepr_process_login_form" value="true" />
        <input type="hidden" name="mepr_is_login_page" value="true" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: `.rememberme` is a class name selector. Looks like the input uses it as a name and id, but not a class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is you are selecting `.rememberme` when the input has a *name* and *id* attribute of 'rememberme' instead of a class. Try adding the class 'rememberme' to the input tag.

```
<label><input class="rememberme" type="checkbox" value="forever" /> remember me</label>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you can't edit the markup in this case.
You have to be specific on CSS selector so the style will apply only on that one. Because all direct child elements (but the one you want to hide) of this form have some classes, we can exclude them on the selector:

```
#mepr_loginform > div:not(.mp-form-row):not(.submit):not(.mp-spacer) {
  display: none;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/artmazi/pen/JQXaWw)

Comment: Do you maybe have any source for your statement?